# Get the event name in redis using java

Tags: redis, event-handling, spring-data-redis

If I listen event in redis, just like command below,

```
$ redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__key*__:*'
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
```

I can get things like

```
"pmessage","__key*__:*","__keyspace@0__:exipre","xxx"
"pmessage","__key*__:*","__keyevent@0__:expired","xxx"
```

So, when I use spring-data-redis to listen events in redis, how can I get the specific event name(like **keyspace@0**:expire), so that not only get the key value like "xxx", but also get the event like `expire` or `expired`, as I don't want to build two topic listener respectively like below:

```
RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
//one for expire
container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter1, new PatternTopic(//topic 1));        
//another for expired
container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter2, new PatternTopic(//topic 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at `KeyspaceEventMessageListener` that subscribes to `__keyevent@*` and then just implement `doHandleMessage`. `Message.getChannel()` holds the raw information about the event type like `__keyevent@0__:expired`.

```java
KeyspaceEventMessageListener eventListener = new KeyspaceEventMessageListener(container) {

    @Override
    protected void doHandleMessage(Message message) {

        String channelInfo = new String(message.getChannel()); // __keyevent@0__:expired
        // ...
    }
};
```